# How to get the functionality of one lua environment from another

Tags: c++, lua, environment

I am involved in the development of a startup and our team is faced with the following problem. We have several lua environments in our C++ application, one environment runs on sol3, and the other is implemented using a regular lua code without any auxiliary libraries. Previously, 2 of these environments worked independently of each other, but now it is necessary to make that an environment with a normal implementation needs functionality that is in written using sol3. How can we access from one environment to another and use all its functionality? Maybe it is possible to combine them somehow? Any ideas will help, thanks a lot

I tried using lua_State* m_state from sol3 to another environment but it didn't help

Comment: You need something like lualanes to send messages between two Lua VMs.  But probably you may rebuild the architecture of your application to find a simpler solution.

Comment: can I bind 2 lua_State to lualanes? If not, then probably this method will not work, because how can I use the functions from the second environment?